# Error al mostrar por pantalla archivo de texto y calcular la media de sueldo

Tags: java

Tengo un problema al intentar mostrar por pantalla un archivo de texto y al calcular la media, el problema es que me salta directamente el catch y no se el motivo por lo que salta y eso hace que no se muestre por pantalla, aquí abajo pondré el código por si alguien me puede ayudar, gracias de antemano.

Estos son los metodos que estan dentro de los metodos que me dan error:

```
public static Treballador LlegirTreballador(Scanner f) {
    Treballador tre = new Treballador();
    tre.codi = f.nextInt();
    tre.nom = f.nextLine();
    tre.edat = f.nextInt();
    tre.sou = f.nextDouble();
    f.nextLine();
    return tre;
}

public static void MostrarTreballador(Treballador tre) {
    System.out.println("codi: " + tre.codi);
    System.out.printf("Nom: %s\n", tre.nom);
    System.out.printf("Edat: %d\n", tre.edat);
    System.out.printf("Sou: %.2f\n", tre.sou);
}
```

Estos son los dos metodos que me dan error:

```
private static void mostrarFitxerTreballador(File fi) {
    Treballador tre;
    try {
        System.out.println("----- Alumnes------");
        Scanner lector = new Scanner(fi);
        while (lector.hasNext()) {
            tre = LlegirTreballador(lector);
            MostrarTreballador(tre);
            System.out.println();

        }
        lector.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.toString());
    }

}

private static double preuMigSou(File fi) {
    Treballador tre;
    double acum = 0;
    int cont = 0;
    try {
        Scanner lector = new Scanner(fi);
        while (lector.hasNext()) {
            tre = LlegirTreballador(lector);
            acum += tre.sou;
            cont++;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.toString());
    }
    if (cont > 0) {
        return acum / cont;
    }
    return 0;
```

Error que me da por pantalla:

```
Escriure Cotxes- Append: false
Codi: 45
Nom: sergi
Edat: 60
Sou: 500

Codi: 0

Escriure Cotxes- Append: true
Codi: 0

----- Alumnes------
java.util.InputMismatchException
java.util.InputMismatchException
Mitja Sou: 0,00
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 12 seconds)
```

Ejemplo de archivo txt

```
40
sergi
22
5000,00
```

Acabo de encontrar lo que me da el error exacto seria esta parte de codigo

```
 public static boolean EscriureTreballador(PrintStream f, Treballador t) {
    Boolean ret = true;
    try {
        f.println(t.codi);
        f.printf("%s\n", t.nom);
        f.printf("%d\n", t.edat);
        f.printf("%.2f\n", t.sou);
        

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.toString());
        ret = false;
    }
    return ret;
}
```

El error esta en el string del nombre porque al quitarlo me va todo perfecto, pero no se porque pasa el error.

Comment: Puedes incluir también qué error te da?

Comment: Hola Sergi. Pulsa en [edit] y pega en la pregunta la traza completa del error.

Comment: @ArianJM Ya he puesto la salida que me da, el error es la ultima parte abajo de alumnes

Comment: Ese error parece indicar que no tienes números cuando esperas leer números, por ejemplo. Podrías ponernos el principio del archivo? Quizá es que está mal formateado de alguna forma...

Comment: @ArianJM acabo de incluir el principio del archivo

Comment: Decia el archivo que lees, no de programación. El txt

Comment: @ArianJM es que no es un archivo completo, es que tengo otros metodos para escribir en el archivo y se va borrando cada vez, si quieres puedo añadir esos metodos para que lo veas

Comment: @ArianJM se refiere a esta parte de tu código: `tre.codi = f.nextInt();
    tre.nom = f.nextLine();
    tre.edat = f.nextInt();
    tre.sou = f.nextDouble();` si los datos de tu archivo no coinciden exactamente con esos tipos y en ese orden estarías teniendo `InputMismatchException` pon un ejemplo del contenido de tu archivo de texto, si hay datos sensibles los puedes cambiar por otros.

Comment: @A.Cedano vale ahora pruebo de arreglar-lo y aviso

Comment: @A.Cedano he puesto un ejemplo de lo que escribo en el archivo de texto, lo escribo directamente con un metodo y despues lo tiene que comprovar no se si eso puede ser un problema

Comment: Revisa el archivo justo alrededor de la parte que falla. Para ello puedes por ejemplo mostrar por pantalla cada línea del archivo directamente comentando temporalmente los next específicos como `nextInt()` o `nextDouble()`. Si vas a trabajar de este modo debes establecer todos los controles posibles para que en el archivo no se guardan datos en una posición con un formato o tipo indebido. Deberás controlar igualmente los posibles espacios en blanco, saltos de línea, etc. Por ejemplo, antes del `40` se ve un espacio, no sé si está así en el archivo o fue al momento de agregarlo aquí.

Comment: @A.Cedano acabo de encontrar el error, estaba en otro metodo que escribe en el archivo, en la parte del nombre, acabo de agregar el metodo si lo puedes mirar un momento te lo agradeceria.

Comment: Sin ver el contexto exacto y el contenido del archivo con el que trabajas es complicado decirte a qué se debe. ¿Dices que si comentas esta línea deja de fallar: `f.printf("%s\n", t.nom);`? ¿La clase `Treballador` tiene un método `getNom()` para obtener el valor de `nom` o un método `toString()` que te muestre el valor de todos los campos de la clase. Convendría hacer una prueba con algo así para ver los datos que hay en la instancia de `Treballador`

Comment: También, para tener más detalles del error, puedes temporalmente imprimir la traza de la excepción y revisarla, es información útil también para cuando preguntes aquí, que pongas la traza completa del error. Para ello puedes poner en el `catch` lo siguiente: `e.printStackTrace();`

Answer (score 0):

El problema puede ser porque estás haciendo `f.nextDouble();` en un número que usa la coma `,` para separar los millares.

Puedes probar 2 cosas. Cambiar la coma por un punto en tu archivo.

O cambiar el Scanner para que acepte comas. Para cambiar el Scanner sería algo como:

```java
Scanner lector = new Scanner(fi).useLocale(new Locale("es", "ES"));
```

Nota: Tienes que importar `import java.util.Locale;`